# I asked a question, and, from a previous question got bad rep due to a reposting, and all the comments on my new question were delete

Tags: support

I am truly outraged. I made a question, and 1 person answered. It helped, but didn't solve the problem. Every single piece of input from members was, from then on, through comments. Now, about 3.5 hrs since I last checked my question, all the comments have been deleted. What do I do now. Tell me, what do I do now?! 90% of the input on my question was on the comments, and some really mentally impaired moderator deleted them all. I needed input urgently, and now, it's all gone. Please, atleast, if a log exists, please by god post them here.

There might not have been that helpful, but we were getting somewhere. Now, I have no means of contacting one of the comments-conversation participants, they've no posts for me to '@'. This is not normal, please, atleast give a warning if it's too long or somewaht offensive, before deleting them all. You mods may not understand, but deleting them all is highly offensive (atleast without some sort of warning). We were just discussing my problem, and suddenly the posts are gone. I'm sorry, but this is not normal.

And now I have -4 rep... I don't understand you people... I gues you don't care if a mod suddenly decides he (or her) doesn't like the comments and deletes them without a warning. I understand I may be being somewhat rude, but sometimes mods here abuse their power. Sorry, but they do. They are destroying something put some effort into (trying, or actually succeeding to help) over god knows wat.

In response to a comment, I intend in no way (I might've, I was really outraged by then. Calmer now) Bashing mods. But some do abuse their powers. Warnings are one of the pillars of a fair community.

Comment: Was it a nice chair?

Comment: I've never heard the expression "Thanks for costing me a chair" before... what does it mean?

Comment: Woops, we use that word here for something like a 'course', like one of the disciplines of the course... i'm not a natve english speaker.

Comment: The comment author most likely deleted their own comments.

Comment: @adrianbanks there we're like 8 of them, and from 3 different persons (including me).

Comment: I hate to say, but SO doesn't operate on deadlines for people

Comment: `Goddamn moderators, I just received a message for being rude, but this is outrageous.` ... so there's probably more to that string of comments than you're telling us here.

Comment: You can't bash mods at the same time as you expect help.

Comment: The question in question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386171/trouble-retrieving-mouse-coordinates

Comment: That was from another question. What happened there was, I urgently needed input, and, as you know, your qeustion get's input from the people who saw it in the first 6-7 mins since you posted, and noone else. All these people were not responding, so I publicly said (and did) that I was reposting a question. This generated -6 rep for me. This is also proof that people care much more for themselves than for others, otherwise they would've understood why I did what I did and not have downvoted it.

Comment: @simchona true, so true, I was hoping a diferent mod (not an abusive one) would see this...

Comment: Bing has the [first five comments in its cache](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cmkyR.png), but these probably aren't what HolyThunder is looking for. (No other cache will have more because the rest are AJAX-loaded.)

Comment: So you barge into a place that offers free help, think it's okay for you to be rude to people and break the site's rules because of your oh so important deadline, call the moderator who cleaned up your comments a retard, and expect to find a symphatetic ear? Whatever works for you, man.

Comment: You can't repost a question and expect to have a good reaction. Just like you can't expect people to obey your deadlines. That's really not how SO works.

Comment: I'm going to make some popcorn, this is better than the Bachelor!

Comment: I didn't expect anyone to obey my deadlines. I set no deadlines whatsoever. I did need urgent help, so I reposted. People shouldn't be mad I reposted, I wouldn't have been. If I understand that that person really needed help, and, for example, I was asleep, and I knew that the chances off that person getting more input in that old(ish) question were slim to none, I wouldn't mind if that person reposted the question due to it being the only way to get the much-needed input they required at that time.

Comment: @Pekka'sReputationBordello I was really outraged by then, I don't mean to insult anyone now. However, do you not agree with me that just deleteing someone's intellectuall property without a warning is more than rude?

Comment: Well, I edited your original question to improve the grammar and bump it back to the front page, so hopefully you'll get another few eyeballs. Based on experience, it might help if you edited it again to explain what you think your code is doing and the different things you've tried.

Comment: @Holy I agree that deleting *all* comments may not have been the right thing to do, but comments *are* second-class citizens around here and subject to deletion any time... not that the community is always fond of that, but it's the way it is. Also AFAIK, there is no log. So the only thing you can do is ask the people who talked to you to re-post their thoughts.

Comment: Reposting questions is adding noise and spam to the system *on purpose*. You're setting a deadline in each question, including this one, saying you'll fail if you don't get help *right now*

Comment: I'm sorry about that deadline thing, I should improve that. Reposting questions is not purposely adding noise to the system though, I just needed some input and knew I'd get some i I reposted it. My intentions were no where near anything malicious.

Comment: I hope the comments on this question don't get deleted.  This is juicy! P.S. @Holy, reposting questions is called "purposely adding noise" because you are intentionally creating duplicates on a site that avoids duplicate content.

Comment: Also, thanks for the editting. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: @HolyThunder You're adding noise by reposting and demanding input.

Comment: And remember everyone here is probably a professional with a day job who's trying to give back to the community a little bit.  Show a little respect and they'll give you anything.

Comment: @simchona I'm not demanding anything. Also, what noise do I actually add? A ew more bytes to their database? I'm sorry for this, but would you rather repost a question and fix your problem when you need to fix it, or not and possibly being late on something?

Comment: *"What do I do now. Tell me, what do I do now?! 90% of the input on my question was on the comments, and some really mentally impaired moderator deleted them all. I needed input urgently, and now, it's all gone. Please, atleast, if a log exists, please by god post them here."* Nope, not demanding at all.

Comment: @Pekka'sReputationBordello fwiw abd for future edification, mods have access to deleted comments post sometime a few months back.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Transcript of deleted comments follows:

---

Like this - //find mouse coordinates var mouseX = 0; var mouseY = 0; $('#canvas').mousemove(function(e){ mouseX = e.pageX + this.offsetLeft; mouseY = e.pageY + this.offsetTop; }); **HolyThunder**

+1 Well done. Not on the answer; that was trivial, but rather on understanding what the problem was. I tell you, sometimes you need real psychic ability on SO...   **davin**

@davin: Thanks :) But honestly it's just the result of some trial-and-error with these kind of issues that makes you remember it well.  **pimvdb**

Dude, I'm new to javascript/jquery, just asking a question... I didn't know that if I used var again it'd create a new local variable. Jeez, I bet you play LoL.    **HolyThunder**

Also, pimvd, it didn't work. Mind taking a look at the question again?  **HolyThunder**

@HolyThunder, please try and understand, there is absolutely no problem with asking a question. Nobody expects you to know everything - if they did, this site wouldn't exist. Although it is expected that you explain yourself slightly more clearly than "tried X, didn't work, here's the code." If you're asking for others' help, think about what you write from their perspective - we can't know what you've tried to do (that code you posted clearly isn't complete), in what circumstances it didn't work, etc. So without telling us, how are we supposed to help? **davin**

@davin Ohhhhhhh.... See, I thought you were talking about me not being able to understand the problem, and "not having psychic abilities.. Oh, sorry abou that then... Anyways, I'm just tryong to get them to use them in another thing, i've been trying to see if they work through an alert that shoes them, if they do I'll use them on something else.    **HolyThunder**

@HolyThunder, this works: http://jsfiddle.net/G8vZG/ which again begs the obvious: "it doesn't work" doesn't help! *How* doesn't it work? *Where* doesn't it work? Show the code in which it doesn't work...    **davin**

Ok, I'm reformulating the post with some more information.  **HolyThunder**

@HolyThunder: Again, you have two `var`s for `started`. Since the variable should persist between function calls of `.click`, you should define it (using `var`) *outside* the function (e.g. at the same level you declared `mouseX`), and update it *without* `var`. Currently, you're creating the variable each time again, and set it to `0`.  pimvdb

@pimvd Oh, sorry. Goddam, twice the same mistake... **HolyThunder**

@pimvd Just fixed that, still not working... I wish there was a jquery or javascript class for this...  **HolyThunder**

@HolyThunder: You should put code which access elements (such as `$("#canvas")`) in the `$(function() {`, because that's what the `$(function() {` is for (running the code only after all elements have become available). **pimvdb**

updated it, still not working... Why, oh why... **HolyThunder**

@pimvd updated it, still not working... Why, oh why...  **HolyThunder**

@HolyThunder, What do you expect to happen if you set a variable to `0` and then directly after put an `if(variable==0){...}else{...}`? When will the `else` ever be evaluated? Why haven't you checked yourself the path of execution; preferably with a debugger, or at least with console logs, or even alerts? Why do you think it "doesn't work"? What is the expected behaviour and what is the actual behaviour? It's like talking to a brick wall - I'm trying to explain to you to **clarify** your queries, and your response is: "Okay, sure thing. But it still doesn't work". Are you serious? **davin**

Alright, sorry if I haven't been clear enough (my head is killing me today, that might have something to do with it. And yeah, I also missed the fact that everytime I'm clicking that it's going to set that var to 0. My objective is to get it to, when I click inside those coordinates (for now it's the white rectangle, I'll be changing it later to the circles themselves) for a white, not-completely opaque circle to appear. Also, any suggestions on a good debugger?  **HolyThunder**

Using chrome's built-in one now. First, it shoed me that game(); wasn't deined, but those were leftovers and I removed those. Now, it shows nothing.    **HolyThunder**

@HolyThunder: Perhaps it's useful to post a test case on http://jsfiddle.net to let others test as to what's wrong. **pimvdb**

@pimvd thanks or the suggestion, done.  **HolyThunder**

@HolyThunder: The circle is drawn when you click in the black area to the bottom left of the red circle. It looks like you set the wrong coordinates since the ones in the `if` clause don't correspond to the white rectangle. **pimvdb**

@HolyThunder: First, it seems that the arguments for `drawRectangle` are `(x, y, width, height)`, so you'll have to add the width to x to get the right x coordinate. Second, to get relative coordinates to the canvas, you should use `e.pageX - this.offsetLeft` because you should use the top left of the canvas as the origin `(0, 0)`. http://jsfiddle.net/wXMyH/1/  **pimvdb**

@HolyThunder, with this large number of comments, you might consider taking the discussion to an [appropriate chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript).    **Ken Redler**

Someone deleted all the comments, wh, oh goddamn why? We were getting somewhere, and now everything has been deleted. WTH. Goddamn moderators, I just received a message for being rude, but this is outrageous. WHY would you ever do this? 90% of input on my question was here!  **HolyThunder**

pimvd, please try to help, I am somewhat desperate since my project is due in 2 days (after tomorrow).  **HolyThunder**

Comment: This answer will self-destruct in two days.

Comment: `@HolyThunder, with this large number of comments, you might consider taking the discussion to an appropriate chatroom. Ken Redler.`

I would've but the thing is, if someone had checked, I didn't log in between that comment and the deletion.

Comment: Also, am I breaking any rules by reposting this on my actual question?

Comment: Do not do that.

Comment: I admire the patience of the person willing to help him, I'd have given up long ago. But I don't really understand where he was being rude until the "goddamn moderators" comment, which was apparently in *response* to an accusation of his being rude. I don't really agree in general with all the overzealous comment deletion by moderators (users should definitely delete their *own* obsolete comments), and I don't see why this user had the book thrown at them. His reaction here has been generally inappropriate, but a certain degree of frustration is understandable.

Answer (score -5):

Police officers enforce laws to keep us safe, right?  But what if a police officer stops a pregnant woman speeding to the hospital to have birth and instead of helping her get there he gives her a ticket?

It's a moderators job to make this site better, right?  I think moderators here (and I use the term 'moderator' loosely here because I'm referring to all kinds of users who moderate at different levels) often become more interested in moderating purely for the sake of moderating than in actually making the site better.

It's fine if moderators want to clean up a question by deleting chatty comments, but for crying out loud use some common sense and wait long enough that you're not likely to ruin someone's day like this.  Or maybe take the time to move relevant info from the comments into the answer (if you don't want to take the time to do that then maybe you should consider whether you're really a good candidate to moderate).  Making this site better ultimately means helping people doesn't it?  So if you have a little patience and let someone get helped before you blow away their comments, that's a GOOD thing.

Comment: You really don't know what you're talking about here, so I'll give you the benefit of the doubt and explain it:  **comments are second-class citizens on this network**.  They are considered to be noise, and do not enjoy the same protections granted to "posts" which are questions and answers.  Moderators are overloaded because of the large amounts of garbage that gets posted.  They don't just go to a comment thread and clean it out for fun - someone had to **flag it** and then the mod read it, checked the flag, and decided the whole string of comments had little value (which is correct).

Comment: I'll also add that you're unlikely to get a lot of support for your point of view by being relatively new and telling everyone how they are doing things wrong without having any sort of context to make your judgments.

Comment: "Or maybe take the time to move relevant info from the comments into the answer (if you don't want to take the time to do that then maybe you should consider whether you're really a good candidate to moderate)." Unless the relevant info from comments is actually a clarification about the question, it doesn't belong in the question. As @JNK mentioned, comments aren't the main focus of the site: good questions are.